# Jumping to Address Bar in Nautilus Like F6 in Windows

Tags: nautilus

How can I go to the address bar in Nautlius using the keyboard? I find it annoying to have the mouse each time I want to copy the path of some files. Not to mention that Nautilus by default don't have an address bar, so I need to spend to keep clicking buttons and menu items until I get the address!! Any idea?

Comment: Press **CTRL+L** to go to address bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to goto the address bar.
- To enable it permanently,Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gconf-editor`
  [image]
- Navigate to apps>>nautilus>>preferences
  [image]
- Put a check mark in **always_use_location_entry**
- Now Address bar will be set in nautilus permanently.
  [image]